# XmlTextWriter default encoding behaves differently to setting encoding to UTF-8

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

I am seeing some behaviour I don't expect with XmlTextWriter. When I specifying the encoding  when I instantiate the writer by either

```
new XmlTextWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8)
```

or

```
XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings(){Encoding = Encoding.UTF8} )
```

the document produced has a leading hex character at the start of the document. Since the C++ parser I am passing the XML to cannot read this, I want to avoid this character. Interestingly, when I create the writer like this

```
new XmlTextWriter(fs, null)
```

I get the exact behaviour I expect. How do I rectreate this instantiation in code without leaving the parameter null?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: What's the "leading hex character"? I expect this is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark‎) which makes sense when you specify UTF-8. Perhaps your C++ parser doesn't know how to decode UTF-8?

Comment: John, that's the whole point of the question. I want to use xmlWriter.Create() but I can't get the same behaviour that I get with new XmlTextWriter()

Comment: groverboy, I expect that you are right (I'm not sure). But (1) I can't control the C++ parser and (2) MSDN says that the default encoding used when null is passed in the constructor is UTF-8, so I guess that the encoding is correct, I just the XmlWriter not to specify the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "leading hex character" is a byte order mark (BOM) as I commented on your question, though I can't be sure without actually seeing it. The C++ parser seems not to know about BOMs, which is odd (see [standard reference by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)).

Let's assume that the C++ parser works only with XML encoded as UTF-8 or one of its character subsets (ASCII, ISO-8859-1, etc.). In that case you have no option but to encode as UTF-8 but exclude the BOM. `XmlWriter` lets you do so as follows:

```
var utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, new XmlWriterSettings() { Encoding = utf8NoBom } );
```

The quote below is from the MSDN reference on [XmlWriter.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162617%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> XmlWriter always writes a Byte Order Mark (BOM) to the underlying data stream; however, some streams must not have a BOM. To omit the BOM, create a new XmlWriterSettings object and set the Encoding property to be a new UTF8Encoding object with the Boolean value in the constructor set to false.

EDIT: If the C++ parser is a general-purpose XML parser then its ignorance of BOMs is odd. If the parser is domain-specific, i.e. if it is always used with files whose character encoding is known (and obviously limited), then its ignorance is not odd. I think this is Spolsky's point.